# How to get Javascript Offset with CSS Translate?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a TopBar that slides in from top after 2 seconds on page load.
For the Slide in animation, I'm using some CSS keyframes with "transform: TranslateY" from -100% to 0%.
The TopBar has "position: fixed", but I want that my main content slides down dynamically when the TopBar comes in.
To do so, I'm coding in javascript one function that can return the visible height of the TopBar, and apply it to the top margin attribute of my main content.
Here is some code:

```
#topbar{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.topbar-animation{
  animation: topbarIn 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes topbarIn {
  0%{
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

The class topbar-animation is added after 2 seconds, and the topbar scrolls from top.

Here is my javascript:

```
var topbar = document.getElementById("topbar");
var mainNav = document.getElementById("main-navbar"); //main-navbar is my top element 

setTimeout(function(){
  topbar.style.display = 'block';
  topbar.classList.add("topbar-animation");
  mainNav.style.marginTop = topbar.offsetHeight + topbar.offsetTop + 'px';
}, 2000);
```

The problem is that topbar.offsetTop is not dynamically changing with the translate animation, and it gives me 0px that is the end point of the animation.
Is there a way I can get the dynamic height of the topbar (that is out of screen) that is changing with the CSS animation?

Answer (score 0):

```
const getTranslateY = (e) => {
    let translateY = 0;
    let transformCss = e.target.style.transform;
    let matchCase = /(-?[0-9\.]+)/g;
    if(transformCss !== null && transformCss.match(matchCase)){
        translateY = transformCss.match(matchCase)[1];
    }
    let finalAxisValue = translateY < 0 ? translateY * -1 : translateY;
    return parseInt(finalAxisValue);
}
```

it worked for me to get the translate property of the element.
**Note:**
in my case i have translate property in inline style

Comment: Hi, I tried but this isn't working with my animation. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I added the "getTranslateY" to my mainNav.style.marginTop, replacing the topbar.offsetTop. I added the translate property as inline style.